# What are minimal system requirements for Salesforce at console mode?

Tags: console

What are minimal system requirements for Salesforce *at console mode*?

http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/6/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_technical_requirements.pdf

The spec above does not make any sense because with this spec on Windows XP I have lagging/freezes and crashes all the time. I have memory crash and unknown crashes in Chrome browser.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> For best performance, we recommend that console users adopt the Google Chrome™ browser and machines with 8 GB of RAM.

Also note that in order to use 8GB of RAM you will need to be on a 64-bit operating system and using a 64-bit browser.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=console2_limitations.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

You should call customer care of salesforce and resolve the issue through them. this is a complex issue to debug through a Q&A site like stack overflow